# Why cannot add strings to combo box? VS C++

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox

When I start my app and click on Triggers tab, there are few select boxes which should load list of items. There is build-in function which works (you can check it if you open scenario file testscen.scx from a menu and then click on Units tab, so the function  `ret = Units_HandleInit(dialog);` calls `Combo_Fill(dialog, IDC_U_TYPE, esdata.unitgroups.head(), L"All");` which loads data to type selectbox (view/editunits.cpp).

When file is not loaded, so I want to do similar thing in module view/edittriggers2.cpp - there is function `BOOL Handle_WM_INITDIALOG2(HWND dialog)`

```
BOOL Handle_WM_INITDIALOG2(HWND dialog)
{
    LCombo_Fill(dialog, IDC_T_UCLASS1, esdata.unitgroups.head(), L"All");
    LCombo_Fill(dialog, IDC_T_UCLASS2, esdata.unitgroups.head(), L"All");
    LCombo_Fill(dialog, IDC_T_UCLASS3, esdata.unitgroups.head(), L"All");
    return TRUE;
}
```

which calls `LCombo_Fill(dialog, IDC_T_UCLASS1, esdata.unitgroups.head(), L"All");` but unfortunately the only item is added the "All". I cannot understand this why, the first is added, and the rest items are not added? I can debug it and go through loop in the function to check that there are messages send to add the string.

```
esdata.unitgroups.head() returns link.
When I debug the LCombo_Fill so it first jumps to [code]
template <class T> T * LinkList<T>::head()
{
    return _head;
}
```

then to

```
inline LRESULT LCombo_Fill(HWND dialog, int id, const Link * list,
        const wchar_t * nosel = NULL)
{
    return LinkComboBox_Fill(GetDlgItem(dialog, id), list, NULL, nosel);
}
```

list is perfectly valid list of Unit types. I checked the addresses and values with Units and this is correct.
nosel is "All"

Then to:

```
LRESULT Combo_AddW(HWND combobox, LPCWSTR string, const void * data)
{
    LRESULT index = Combo_AddStringW(combobox, string);
    Combo_SetItemData(combobox, index, data);

    return index;
}
```

Then to:

```
int LinkComboBox_Fill(HWND combobox, const Link *list, const Link *select,
        const wchar_t * nosel)
{
    int ret = -1;

    SendMessage(combobox, CB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);

    if (nosel)
        Combo_AddW(combobox, nosel, NULL);

    for (; list; list = list->next())
    {
        LRESULT index = Combo_AddW(combobox, list->name(), list);

        if (list == select)
        {
            SendMessage(combobox, CB_SETCURSEL, index, 0);
            ret = index;
        }
    }

    if (ret == -1 && nosel)
    {
        SendMessage(combobox, CB_SETCURSEL, 0, 0);
        ret = 0;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Then to:

```
LRESULT Combo_AddW(HWND combobox, LPCWSTR string, const void * data)
{
    LRESULT index = Combo_AddStringW(combobox, string);
    Combo_SetItemData(combobox, index, data);

    return index;
}
```

Finally:

```
inline LRESULT Combo_SetItemData(HWND control, WPARAM index, const void * ptr)
{
    // LPARAM is defined as a LONG_PTR by the documentation. Hopefully that
    // won't change.
    return SendMessageW(control, CB_SETITEMDATA, index,
        reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(ptr));
}
// (the comments above are not of me)
```

ptr is 0x00000000

Then in the loop the same functions are called:

```
LRESULT index = Combo_AddStringW(combobox, string);
Combo_SetItemData(combobox, index, data);
```

So I need help to find the reason why the combo box is not filled with the values which are passed through loop.

Note:
Debug in the loop:
`res = SendMessageW(control, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)string);`
res is 1

`LRESULT index = Combo_AddStringW(combobox, string);`
result is 1 (looks like index, this is increased while looping)

in Combo_SetItemData:
`LRESULT res = SendMessageW(control, CB_SETITEMDATA, index,
        reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(ptr));`
res is 1

I did not wrote the program and the source code is complex. I cannot to simplify it, but does someone have idea why the items are not added except the first item? None of the items which should be added to combo box is added.

Project link:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/autots/files/AOKTS%20update/aokts-1.0.1%20r72%20update_test.zip/download
Project file name: aokts.sln

Comment: From the picture it looks like the drop list is trying to open but is too small. Out of curiosity, did you try to resize the drop list. If you have the dialog in a resource file you can click on the arrow of the combobox and resize it there

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem! It's my first combo box / "select box".

Comment: BTW: Is it possible to use the name of the constant in the similar way like: `LCombo_Fill(dialog, IDC_T_UCLASS + index, esdata.unitgroups.head(), L"All");`? So I could use loop to genarate controls.

Comment: I am not really sure without trying it first

Comment: I meant to genarate items into multiple combo boxes.

Comment: Oh, then yes. We use loops to put items in a config file in multiple combo boxes. in your loop you could just name the actual Combobox and addstring in each step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resize the Combobox in order to see other addition. If you have the dialog in a resource file you can click on the arrow of the combobox and resize it there.